# Exibição de caracteres latinos em uma String

Tags: java, codificação-de-caracteres

Como faço para exibir caráteres latinos como conteúdo de uma página web?

Esse conteúdo a ser exibido é escrito em java, que deve codifica-lo corretamente e retornar um **String**com os valores a serem escritos para o servidor.

Estou usando a classe **URLEncoder** do java.

```
 news = URLEncoder.encode(newsString, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a codificação da sua página estiver correta, por exemplo ao enviar o cabeçalho HTTP:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Ou ao especificá-la no próprio HTML:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

ou

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Então a princípio você não precisa fazer nada: a classe `String` já trabalha com caracteres Unicode (sendo representada internamente por UTF-16 se não me engano), e o próprio *webserver* deve ser capaz de converter essa string em bytes conforme a codificação desejada (apenas certifique-se que a codificação que você está *declarando* é a mesma codificação que o servidor está *usando*).

Outras codificações além de UTF-8 podem ser usadas (Cp1252 / Windows-1252 ou ISO-8859-1 / ISO-Latin ou alguma outra), mas não recomendo: UTF-8 é bem universal, e deve ser entendida por qualquer *browser* não pré-histórico.

Por fim, um comentário sobre o [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html): o que ele faz é codificar uma string de forma que ela possa ser usada como URL. Isso *não é a mesma coisa* que codificá-la de modo a ser usada como **conteúdo** de uma página HTML - se você usar esse método e em seguida incluir o resultado numa página, o usuário vai ver os caracteres "estranhos". Caso você precise muito codificar sua string em ASCII, você precisa transformar os caracteres Unicode em [entidades HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) - que é um processo distinto, e não sei como fazer em Java. Mas a princípio isso não deve ser necessário - e se for, deve aumentar consideravelmente o tamanho da página gerada.

Comment: sua ideia funcionou. Criei um arquivo e escrevi em UTF-8, mesmo